# Where are my WCF client constructor overloads?

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor

I'm creating a simple WCF service (MailService), and have added a service reference to a client project. The object browser in the client project is successfully showing the MailService metadata, including an object called MailServiceClient that has 4 overloads for its constructor.

I want to use the single string parameter constructor, to nominate the endpoint name, for this client object:

```
MailServiceClient client = 
    new MailServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMailService");
```

Problem is: VS2008 only sees the parameterless constructor, and that's stopping me going any further. It also (therefore?) can't see my only method, SendEmails(), in that client object as well.

Without showing every single line of code for the service, can anyone recognise what's I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Oh holy sweet Jesus. I was using the same class name for the containing class (MailServiceClient) as I was for the client object. I just needed to zoom out and see that. Long day. Just me here. Needed another pair of eyes. Thanks Josh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's unusual. I've seen it *not* have the parameterless constructor when there are multiple endpoints but I've never seen it *only* have the parameterless constructor. It sounds like maybe you have a partial class somewhere in a different namespace. Or maybe the Reference.cs generation failed for some reason. Right click on MailServiceClient and "Go To Definition". You should be able to tell right away if you're constructing the wrong class or there's a partial class disconnect.

Comment: Got it, thanks - see comment above. 'Go To Definition' immediately revealed the duplication of the namespace, which I hadn't even considered.

Comment: Josh, you're a legend - how on earth did you intuition figure that one out? It must be black magic :)